# How to get filename from remote location into string in Python?

Tags: python, server

I need to get filename located in /home/config folder into string in Python. Folder is located on remote location.
Here is my code:

```
w=pxssh.pxssh()
w.login('11.24.33,98','root','')
w.sendline('cd /home/config')
w.prompt()
w.sendline('find ./  -printf "%f\n"')
w.prompt()
filename=w.before
print filename
```

This is output of command 'print filename':

```
find ./  -printf "%f
> "
./
upgrade_fast_15A
```

where 'upgrade_fast_15A' is actully filename.

'Filename' contains  executed command also, and it should contain filename only.
How could I solve this?

Comment: please add the output as code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to know that you only want the final
line of the string. However, the output lines are separated by
2 chars, `\r\n` not just newline, and the output ends with
these 2 chars, so you want:

```
 filename = w.before.split('\r\n')[-2]
```

You can also suppress output of the command with

```
w.sendline('stty -echo')
w.prompt()
```

at the start, but you will still have to handle the `\r\n`.